# VBA Fill online form that is NOT a textarea

Tags: html, vba, excel, textarea

Good morning,

I have created a basic VBA program in Excel that auto fills an online form by using: `IE.Document.getElementById(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")).Value = Worksheets("CASTGT").Range("B1")`

This works fine, when the online form is using textareas (i.e. under inspect element I see):

```
<div class = "fields-container">
   <div class = "name long-field">
      <textarea id = "random-name" placeholder= "randomstuff" style="height: 24px;: ></textarea>
```

However, now my work is moving to a form that doesn't seem to use textareas anymore. The new form that I would like to fill in looks like this under inspect element:

```
<label class="has-float-label shadow" for="random-name"> == $0
   <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <input value id="random-name" style="box-sizing: content-box; 2px;">
```

Whenever I try using the same `IE.Document.getElementById(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")).Value = Worksheets("CASTGT").Range("B1")` , it may fill out a letter or two, but then when I click in any other box on the form, the couple letters it inputed will delete

I hope there is an easy solution to this, but any help will be very appreciated. Please let me know if you need to see anymore of the code or InspectElement

Comment: Can you share a link? This is a common occurence with javascript webpages particularly if it has default text as well. It particular, it may have javascript events tied into the element .

Comment: @QHarr Unfortunatly due to security reasons I can't share the site. However if there's specifc parts of the Inspect Element (or anything else on the page) that you need to see, I can get those for you to look at

Comment: Are there any associated events you can see like onClick ? You may need to experiment with simulating pressing Enter or the like.

Comment: @QHarr I don't see any events such as onClick, however it does fall under an "event-container". Does this mean it's getting called from somewhere else and I just have to look around? I also messed around with using `.Click` on the input field first, but that doesnt seem to help. Is there a different way to simulate hitting Enter?

Comment: Is there default text already present?

Comment: SendKeys after you have set focus on the element (dreaded sendkeys!)

Comment: @Qharr Nope, nothing present already. For the couple textareas that are there (that I am able to edit fine), there is some defualt text. But for all these other ones that I'm having trouble with have nothing

Comment: @SIM want to wade in here with some divination?

Comment: Have you tried with selenium basic? It is sometimes easier with windows tiled side by side to play around with different methods in the VBE whilst observing the result in the automated browser window? Other than that.. more HTML may help.

Comment: @QHarr unfortunately I can't download any programs on my work computers (or access the site from home), so I'm very limited in my options. I'm out of the office for a week, so I will re-attack when I get back home. Thank you for your help!